# How to download a back up of Math.SE

Tags: discussion, data-dump

I like this site a lot, but I worry that at some point, as with all things in life, it will come to an end. Is there a way to take a back up of the entire site and download it, or at least all the questions/answers my account asked?

Comment: See https://archive.org/details/stackexchange

Comment: [Two](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4979) [related](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9148) threads.

Comment: I'm always skeptical that my hard drive might outlast SE... but, having the data-dump available is nice.

Comment: Good question. The mathematics on this site is far too precious for humanity to ever lose.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Beautifully said. Couldn't agree more.

Answer (score -9):

1. Every day, I think about that.
2. I am planning to take 'some' of my answers and move them to some personal blog or to my computer.
3. However, I have around 2000 answers and I don't like all of them but some of them took me a few days to polish and those are the ones I want to retrieve.
4. I am thinking in a 'manual process' but it looks cumbersome.

By the way, sometimes ago I tried to retrieve my tweets ( in Twitter ). They told me they have to prepare a kind of a zip. I didn't receive any thing and they never contacted me anymore. I guess it goes along your initial idea.

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer to the question. It seems like the discussion of the question stops at "every day I think about this." Did you have an actual approach in mind?